# Attempting to use for loop in R to create graphs but am getting error message

Tags: r, file, for-loop, graph

I am attempting to create multiple graphs from a large dataset in R using a for loop. The dataset includes 5 instruments and multiple dates - I am attempting to create graphs for each date within each instrument.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Phos =  read.csv("Tot-P.csv", header = TRUE)

InstrumentA = subset(Phos, Phos$Instrument == "A") 
InstrumentB = subset(Phos, Phos$Instrument == "B") 
InstrumentC = subset(Phos, Phos$Instrument == "C") 
InstrumentD = subset(Phos, Phos$Instrument == "D") 
InstrumentE = subset(Phos, Phos$Instrument == "E") 


AllDatesA = unique(InstrumentA$Date)
for (i in 1:length(AllDatesA)) {
  Date.i = AllDatesA[i]
  InstrumentA.i = InstrumentA[InstrumentA$Date == Date.i, ]
  YourFileName = paste(Date.i, ".jpg", sep = "")
  jpeg(file = YourFileName)
  plot(x = InstrumentA.i$Sample_ID, y = InstrumentA.i$Results, xlab = "Sample ID", 
       ylab = "Concentration (mg P/l)", main = Date.i)
  dev.off()
}

AllDatesB = unique(InstrumentB$Date)
for (i in 1:length(AllDatesB)) {
  Date.i = AllDatesB[i]
  InstrumentB.i = InstrumentB[InstrumentB$Date == Date.i, ]
  YourFileName = paste(Date.i, ".jpg", sep = "")
  jpeg(file = YourFileName)
  plot(x = InstrumentB.i$Sample_ID, y = InstrumentB.i$Results, xlab = "Sample ID", 
       ylab = "Concentration (mg P/l)", main = Date.i)
  dev.off()
}

AllDatesC = unique(InstrumentC$Date)
for (i in 1:length(AllDatesC)) {
  Date.i = AllDatesC[i]
  InstrumentC.i = InstrumentC[InstrumentC$Date == Date.i, ]
  YourFileName = paste(Date.i, ".jpg", sep = "")
  jpeg(file = YourFileName)
  plot(x = InstrumentC.i$Sample_ID, y = InstrumentC.i$Results, xlab = "Sample ID", 
       ylab = "Concentration (mg P/l)", main = Date.i)
  dev.off()
}

AllDatesD = unique(InstrumentD$Date)
for (i in 1:length(AllDatesD)) {
  Date.i = AllDatesD[i]
  InstrumentD.i = InstrumentD[InstrumentD$Date == Date.i, ]
  YourFileName = paste(Date.i, ".jpg", sep = "")
  jpeg(file = YourFileName)
  plot(x = InstrumentA.i$Sample_ID, y = InstrumentA.i$Results, xlab = "Sample ID", 
       ylab = "Concentration (mg P/l)", main = Date.i)
  dev.off()
}

AllDatesE = unique(InstrumentE$Date)
for (i in 1:length(AllDatesE)) {
  Date.i = AllDatesE[i]
  InstrumentE.i = InstrumentE[InstrumentE$Date == Date.i, ]
  YourFileName = paste(Date.i, ".jpg", sep = "")
  jpeg(file = YourFileName)
  plot(x = InstrumentE.i$Sample_ID, y = InstrumentE.i$Results, xlab = "Sample ID", 
       ylab = "Concentration (mg P/l)", main = Date.i)
  dev.off()
}
```

When I attempt to run the first for loop, I receive the following error message:

Error in devoff():
QuartzBitmap_Output = unable to open file '9/23/19.jpg'

I think that this error might be related to the file path, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi ktarr24, could you edit your question to include example data? To make this a *minimal* reproducible example, perhaps just use the `InstrumentA ` dataset, since all others seem repetitive

Comment: Problem is simple, You have to change the name of the file name. You can not use `/` slash in the file name, therefore, you are getting the error

Answer (score 0):

You can easily avoid this error by changing the file name. You can use `.` in the file name. Make following changes:

```
for (i in 1:length(AllDatesA)) {
  Date.i = AllDatesA[i]
  InstrumentA.i = InstrumentA[InstrumentA$Date == Date.i, ]
  YourFileName = paste(Date.i, ".jpg", sep = "")
  YourFileName = gsub("/", ".", YourFileName)
  jpeg(file = YourFileName)
  plot(x = InstrumentA.i$Sample_ID, y = InstrumentA.i$Results, xlab = "Sample ID", 
       ylab = "Concentration (mg P/l)", main = Date.i)
  dev.off()
}
```

Now run this.